# Extract Columns from Matrix

Tags: matrix

I want to extract columns 3 and 4 from the matrix below:

```
mat1=Table[{n, ksi, 
   r = c /. FindRoot[
      SpheroidalS1[1, n, c, ksi], {c, BesselJZero[n + 1/2, 1]}
    ],
   r*ksi},
 {n, 4}, {ksi, {100, 250, 600, 950}}
] // Flatten[#, 1] & // Prepend[(Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"n", "ksi", "c", "c*ksi"})] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &

mat2=mat1[[3;;4,1;;16]]
```

But I get the following message:

> Part::take: Cannot take positions 3 through 4 in `Grid[Prepend[{n,ksi,c,c*ksi}][{{1,100,4.66544,466.544},<<14>>,{4,950,8.18302 -3.30575*10^-6 I,7773.87 -0.00314046 I}}],Frame->All]`. >>

What gives?

Comment: Replace `// Grid` with `;mat1//Grid` in your code. Then run `mat1[[All, 3 ;; 4]]`

Comment: More generally, never include the wrapper (e.g., `Grid`, `Table`, `Row`, `Column`) as part of the definition of the data. You can use parentheses to isolate the wrapper from the definition, e.g., `(mat1 = ...)//Grid[#, Frame -> All] &`

Answer (score 2):

the problem is `mat1` is not a matrix or list, but a `Grid`.  Your `Table` (with header row) appears as the first part of the `Grid` object, so you can do this:

```
 mat1[[1,All, 3 ;; 4]]
```

Note you also transposed the row/column order.

If you want to display that as a `Grid` : `mat1[[1, All, 3 ;; 4]] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &`

Really you'd be better off to save the `Table` and only apply `Grid` when you want to display in formatted form. One way to do that is to add parenthesis to your code:

```
(  mat1 = Table[]... ) // Grid
```

Comment: I don't get the desired results through:  mat1[[1,All, 3 ;; 4]]. My results are {{1, 600, 4.4951, 2697.06}, {1, 950, 4.49248, 4267.86}}. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had to delete //Grid[#, Frame -> All] & and then as you suggested mat2 = mat1[[1, All, 3 ;; 4]]. Thank you all for your recommendations!

Comment: With the headings `mat1[[All, 3;;4]]` or `mat1[[All, {3,4}]]`. Without the headings `mat1[[2;;, 3;;4]]` or `mat1[[2;;, {3,4}]]`